# IF statement giving wrong answer whereas ELSE IF is working fine

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am solving [**Count Occurences of Anagrams**](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/count-occurences-of-anagrams5839/1#) question on GeekForGeeks.

```cpp
int search(string ana, string s) {

    unordered_map<char, int> m;
    for(auto it : ana) m[it]++;

    int k=ana.length();
    int count=m.size();
    
    int i=0, j=0;
    int ans=0;
    
    while(j<s.length()){
    
        if(m.find(s[j])!=m.end()){
            m[s[j]]--;
            if(m[s[j]]==0) count--;
        }
         
        if(j-i+1<k) j++;
        
       if(j-i+1==k){  //**else if works**
           
            if(count==0) ans++;
           
            if(m.find(s[i])!=m.end()){
                m[s[i]]++;
                if(m[s[i]]==1) count++;
            }

            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

This code works when using `else if(j-i+1==k)`, but when using simply `if(j-i+1==k)` it gives the wrong answer.

for test case:

```
s = forxxorfxdofr
ana = for
Output: 3
```

But when using only `if` it gives

```
Output :0
```

Comment: What's the question?  If `else if` works, use that.  Are you asking why you need else if instead of just if to make it work?

Comment: Put the parts of the question you linked to that is needed to solve the problem in your question as text, not as a link.

Comment: That suggests there are times when `j-i+1>k`, which those two options handle differently.

Comment: By works do you mean raises a robot army to crush mankind? If that's the case I don't want to help you.

Comment: Changing the `else if` to an `if` isn't a simplification ... it's changing the logic of the code. When `j-i+1 == k-1`, the `++j` will make the second test execute in the `if` case, but it won't in the `else if` case.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes i am not able to understand what difference does else if makes to simple if statement in this code

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that after this if statement

```
    if(j-i+1<k) j++;
```

the variable j is incremented and the next if statement

```
   if(j-i+1==k){  /
```

in any case gets the control and can evaluate to true.

If to use if else statement

```
    if(j-i+1<k) j++;
    
    else if(j-i+1==k){  /
```

then if the first if statement was evaluated the else if statement will be skipped.

So logically the behavior is different for these two code snippets.

Here is a simplified demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int x = 0;
    
    if ( x == 0 ) ++x;
    if ( x == 1 ) ++x;
    
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    
    x = 0;
    
    if ( x == 0 ) ++x;
    else if ( x == 1 ) ++x;
    
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
x = 2
x = 1
```

Investigate it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought both conditions can not be true at once so else if seemed to be irrelevant but j++ was there.